# Slider height technique

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resize

I have a code for bootstrap carousel. But when decreasing  window to smaller screen the height is not decreasing. I've used JQuery, but still facing problem.

```
<div class="container-fluid nopad">
    <div class="row-fluid nopad">
        <div class="col-lg-12 top_slider">
            <!-- Slider -->
            <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel_top" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="list-box">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="img/slides/slide-01.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/slides/slide-02.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/slides/slide-03.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS is

```
.top_slider{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 !Important;

}
.top_slider .carousel{
    width:100%;
}
.top_slider .carousel-inner .item{
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
}
.top_slider .carousel-inner .item  img{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-50%);
    z-index:1;
}
```

**When checking my file in my smartphone, getting this same problem**. I don't know  my JQuery code has any error. This is the code i've used

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj_height_on_ready= $('.top_slider .carousel-inner .item  img').height();
    if($(window).width() <= 769){
            $('.top_slider .carousel-inner .item').css({"height": obj_height_on_ready});
            $('.short_desc_tab').text(obj_height_on_ready);
        }
        else{
            $('.top_slider .carousel-inner .item').css({"height": "400"});

        }


});
```

[image: This is the demo, unwanted space below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `height:400px` of your `.item` elements. In addition your images inside the `.item` elements are absolute positioned. Replace your `.top_slider .carousel-inner .item img` with the following, and the carousel is completely responsive. You dont even need your jQuery.

```
.top_slider .carousel-inner .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: still facing problem, some unwanted pixels of height are at bottom in a background #f2f2f2